# Fastest way to get .Count from large table in Entity Framework using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using `Entity Framework` and `LINQ`. I have a table which has around half a million records and I want to get `.Count()` of a table. What is the best way to do that?

I have tried this:

```
// Without WHERE condition. Execution Time = 5864 miliseconds
var count = context.MyTable
                   .AsNoTracking()
                   .Count();

// With WHERE condition. Execution Time = 9825 miliseconds
var count = context.MyTable
                   .AsNoTracking()
                   .Count(x => !x.IsDeleted && (x.Column.Contains(keyword) || x.Column2.Contains(keyword) || x.Column3.Contains(keyword)));
```

Is there any other way or approach to improve this query?

Comment: execute the query directly in the native SQL dialect of the underlying database engine (MSSQL?), and profile it. LINQ-to-entities should create a straighforward `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE ...` statement from your code, with little potential for optimization. It is evident that the version with `WHERE` is considerably slower, probably `IsDeleted` is boolean and hardly improves with indexing, and `Contains` are translated to `LIKE` and will give full table scans in the execution plan most of the time.

Comment: What is the execution plan of the query? Are the columns indexed? How much do the queries take when you execute them directly against the database?

Comment: The `AsNoTracking` call here is redundant by the way.

Comment: BTW that `x.Column.Contains(keyword)` is evil. It maps to `Column LIKE '%keyword%'` which *can't* use indexes, unless you use full text search. This query is forced to scan everything with the `IsDeleted` flag without benefit of indexing. If you *do* want to perform such an open-ended query, use FTS

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Both of them in SQL are quick. Yes, `Column` and `Column2` are indexed.

Comment: Before you do any sort of performance analysis, always be sure to clear the cache(s) so you don't get skewed results. Also what are your Column1, Column2 and Column3 definitions? What is their entropy level like? Does the index actually benefit or hinder you in this case?

Comment: If you say that the same query in SQL is quick - log which query is generated by EF (with `context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine` or similar) and see if it's what you expect. Won't hurt also if you tell us what database you are actually using.

Comment: @CSharper it doesn't matter if they are indexed or not. `Column LIKE '%keyword%'` can't use any indexes. BTW which SQL queries did you try? Did you actually use `AND (Column LIKE '%keyword%' OR Column2 LIKE '%keyword%' or Column3 LIKE '%keyword%'` ?

Comment: @Evk I am using `SQL Server 2014`. Let me see what I am getting by using `Log` and I'll go from there.

Comment: You may want to consider getting LINQPad and using it to examine the generated SQL and for timing. It is a wonderful tool.